# IE "About:Tab" page hijacked

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, internet-explorer-8, malware, hijack

Client o' mine, running Windows 7 64-bit, installed Kiwee Toolbar and then uninstalled it. The software is pretty much gone except for one last thing:

The About:Tab IE page redirects to a Kiwee search page.

I have temporarily disabled the "New Tab" page via Internet Explorer's options, but it annoys me.

I have scanned with multiple tools. Spyware Doctor purports to removed it, but they want money to remove it. I would buy it -if- I could be certain it would fix the problem. I've also searched the registry and the filesystem for instances of the program, plus I've removed Kiwee manually via the many manual uninstalls out there.

IE's AboutURLs registry entry still points to res://ieframe.dll/tabswelcome.htm and if I enter that URL into IE, the correct New Tab page comes up.

I've also done the advanced reset on IE. I haven't tried to reinstall it. I'm scared! ;-)

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution:

http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/InternetExplorer/thread/375045b6-d59c-44a4-a3c1-87b8fa472f83

It requires registry tampering, but that's what you have to do sometimes.

Comment: Yes! I wasn't looking here:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\AboutURLs

There was a URL in the Tabs key. I changed it back to "res://ieframe.dll/tabswelcome.htm" and all is well.